# Set dynamic IP to virtual machines on vSphere

Tags: vmware, vsphere, vmware-workstation, vcenter

Hi everyone : I'm using an evaluation license on vSphere and wanted to try out some stuff.

I have two machines connected to a vSwitch, a VMKernel well configured with subnet 192.168.0.0/24.

The thing is I don't want to set IP of my machines manually. I want it to be set dynamically via DHCP directly via vSphere (the same way in Workstation machines get IPs after creation).

I've tried to set an IP pool, associate it to my network but still in the VM properties, transient IP is greyed out, leaving me with "static" mode only.

Could you explain how to perform this ?

Thanks for you time !

Comment: I think what you're looking for are called IP Pools. Read the documentation, configure an ip pool and then associate it with a portgroup

Comment: I've also tried this out and didn't work as expected : IP Pool configured, Network configured to use IP Pool but my VM does not retrieve an IP...

In the options of the VM the option "use transient IP" (from the IP Pool, from what i've understood) is greyed out. And only the 'Static IP address' option is available.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% this is what you want to do, but try going to the VM summary tab and then:
VM Hardware -> Edit Settings.
Choose a Network adapter. Change the MAC address to manual, and insert the MAC address that you DHCP knows of.